# How to hide download link from callout popup in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, callouts

My simple requirement is to hide the "DOWNLOAD" action from callout and want to keep other options as it is. Kindly refer below image.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried for this particular case but I am sure it should work in this case too.You can inspect the element using F12 ( Deeveloper tool) and get the id or class of the download link and then add DISPLAY:NONE; css property to hide it.

Also you can refer this blog for better understanding
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/07/08/hideremovecustomize-callout-actions-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I have tried the link you shared, but it is just removing the footer altogether and adding another customized footer. Tried F12 (Developer tool), but not working.

Comment: there can refer this blogs                                      http://www.eliostruyf.com/hiding-the-social-actions-follow-share-from-the-document-libraries-in-sharepoint-2013/